# Amplifiying a 40kHz square signal to a higher frequency

Tags: amplifier, frequency, igbt

So I designed a circuit with these two main parts:
1. The timer, powered by 12V DC consists of a 555 timer circuit enhanced with Op-Amp regulator circuit. This part is connected to irg4ph40upbf IGBT.
2. Voltage regulator, powered by 24V DC.

I connected those two, and I already got the results that I wanted. The thing is, these two part is supposed to be connected to a pulse transformer that has working frequency at 50 kHz. the circuit I created only has max freq of 40 kHz. How can I amplify this freq to my desired freq?

Comment: Reduce the value of your 555 timing capacitor by 25%.

Comment: You cannot "amplify" a frequency...!! Wrong term used.

Comment: What prevents the pulse transformer working at 40 kHz? That's not so very far below its nominal working freq?

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways.

1. Reduce the size of the timing capacitor
2. Reduce the resistance(s) of the two timing resistors slightly
3. Bring the "control" voltage on pin 5 down a little.

I'd go with @WhatRoughBeast's comment above. Reduce the cap.